# Visual Studio Signing executable with Certificate

Tags: visual-studio, certificate, publish

Visual studio offers me the ability to Sign my assembly / Manifest through the public wizard. However, in order to utilize this functionality, it seems as though I am required to create an installer for my program. I do not want to have to install my executable (anywhere). I would much rather be able to build a single executable and copy this executable into multiple directories (All with a certificate).

I'm assuming there must be some workaround for this, and I would love to hear any suggestions.

Comment: Important to know in this context - [Strong naming in Visual Studio vs. Authenticode signing with a well-known CA certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4469646/465053)

Answer (score 8):

1. Open your project.
2. Under `Solution Explorer`, double click on `Properties`.
3. Click `Signing`.
4. Click `Sign the assembly`.
5. Click the dropdown box, and then select `<New...>`.
6. Enter in your desired information and click `OK`.

Comment: This is what I have been doing? Was I mistaken - I could have sworn this required me to make an installer

Comment: No this does not require an installer. When you build the application, it is automatically signed.

Comment: Is there some simple way to verify the certificate is present? Thank you

Comment: You can use "sn -vf myassembly.dll" (with your assembly name) at a command prompt. That tells you if the assembly is "strongly named", which is what the signing tab on project properties controls. If you meant signing with an Authenticode  certificate, that's something else entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the concise instructions.  I knew there must be an easier way than doing this from the command line!

Comment: I signed like this, still when i send the exe to someone else it is flagged as virus. what am i doing wrong