# How to install `Installer Projects` for Visual Studio 2019

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2019

When ever I try to install the `Installer Project`-Package for Visual Studio 2019 I get these Log:

```
27.02.2020 10:30:57 - -------------------------------------------
27.02.2020 10:30:57 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
27.02.2020 10:30:57 - -------------------------------------------
27.02.2020 10:31:03 - Initializing Install...
27.02.2020 10:31:07 - Extension Details...
27.02.2020 10:31:07 -   Identifier         : VSInstallerProjects
27.02.2020 10:31:07 -   Name               : Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects
27.02.2020 10:31:07 -   Author             : Microsoft
27.02.2020 10:31:07 -   Version            : 0.9.6
27.02.2020 10:31:07 -   Description        : This official Microsoft extension provides support for Visual Studio Installer Projects in Visual Studio.
27.02.2020 10:31:07 -   Locale             : en-US
27.02.2020 10:31:07 -   MoreInfoURL        : 
27.02.2020 10:31:07 -   InstalledByMSI     : False
27.02.2020 10:31:07 -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.6.1,)
27.02.2020 10:31:07 - 
27.02.2020 10:31:09 -   SignatureState     : ValidSignature
27.02.2020 10:31:09 -   SignedBy           : Microsoft Corporation
27.02.2020 10:31:09 -   Certificate Info   : 
27.02.2020 10:31:09 -       -------------------------------------------------------
27.02.2020 10:31:09 -       [Subject]       : CN=Microsoft Corporation, OU=OPC, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
27.02.2020 10:31:09 -       [Issuer]        : CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA 2010, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
27.02.2020 10:31:09 -       [Serial Number] : 3300000305DFD27DFE8F86CDB3000000000305
27.02.2020 10:31:09 -       [Not Before]    : 05.06.2019 19:36:58
27.02.2020 10:31:09 -       [Not After]     : 03.06.2020 19:36:58
27.02.2020 10:31:09 -       [Thumbprint]    : 417A476992589EA95299F5057960010675759457
27.02.2020 10:31:09 - 
27.02.2020 10:31:09 -   Supported Products : 
27.02.2020 10:31:09 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
27.02.2020 10:31:09 -           Version : [15.0,17.0)
27.02.2020 10:31:09 - 
27.02.2020 10:31:09 -   References         : 
27.02.2020 10:31:09 -   Prerequisites      : 
27.02.2020 10:31:09 -       -------------------------------------------------------
27.02.2020 10:31:09 -       Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell
27.02.2020 10:31:09 -       Name         : Visual Studio Min Shell
27.02.2020 10:31:09 -       Version      : [15.0.26205,17.0)
27.02.2020 10:31:09 - 
27.02.2020 10:31:09 -       -------------------------------------------------------
27.02.2020 10:31:09 -       Identifier   : Microsoft.Component.ClickOnce
27.02.2020 10:31:09 -       Name         : ClickOnce Publishing
27.02.2020 10:31:09 -       Version      : [15.0,17.0)
27.02.2020 10:31:09 - 
27.02.2020 10:31:09 - Signature Details...
27.02.2020 10:31:09 -   Extension is signed with a valid signature.
27.02.2020 10:31:09 - 
27.02.2020 10:31:09 - System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070490): Element nicht gefunden. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)
   bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration.ISetupConfiguration2.GetInstanceForPath(String path)
   bei VSIXInstaller.LocationBasedSKU..ctor(String appidInstallPath, String appidName, Version vsVersion, String edition, String rootSuffix)
   bei VSIXInstaller.LocationBasedSKU..ctor(String appidInstallPath, String appidName, Version vsVersion, String edition, String rootSuffix, IntPtr alternateUserToken)
   bei VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableDataImpl(IInstallableExtension extension, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   bei VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   bei VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.ComputeInstallableExtensions(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported, Boolean isExtensionPack, IDictionary`2 skuDataMapping, IList`1 installableExtensionsPaths)
   bei VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   bei VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   bei System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   bei System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

Does anyone knows what these Errors means and what I can do?

Comment: Looks like a missing COM object indicative of a missing run-time or prerequisite - or a corrupted installation. Try on a different machine or on a virtual? Also try to log in with a different admin-rights account and [maybe skim this list for other things to test and rule out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60374125/129130). Not sure this package works in 2019? Try 2017 on a virtual?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone knows what these Errors means and what I can do?

The [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) extension  is installed in VS2019 successfully in my side. So I suspect something is wrong with your VS environment. Please follow these steps to troubleshoot your issue:

**1)** delete all VS2019 component caches under `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxxxx\ComponentModelCache`

**2)** disable any third party extensions under `Extensions`-->`Manage Extensions` to prevent any other extensions affect it.

**3)** [do a repair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) in VS installer

**4)** update your VS2019 to the latest version and do not forget to update your OS version in case there are some fixes.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I followed all your steps, but I still get the Error. I will try to just reinstall Visual Studio and hope it works then. Do not have time for it right now but if it works the next days I will Update this Question.