# What does Windows installer "Assembly Error:Access is denied." mean?

Tags: windows-installer

I've done a bunch of Google searches and all I've found is neededing to have modify allowed on the temp folder - it is.

This is happening on just 2 computers (customers of ours) out of probably 40,000 computers. So it's something weird/unusual.

The very end of the installer log is:

```
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:844]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=PublishProduct,Description=Publishing product information,)
Action 11:29:57: PublishProduct. Publishing product information
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:847]: Executing op: CleanupConfigData()
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:847]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\A3B90715F4ABD9746B45D288F4C39CEB\Patches 3: 2 
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:847]: Executing op: RegisterPatchOrder(Continue=0,SequenceType=1,Remove=0)
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:848]: Note: 1: 1402 2: UNKNOWN\Products\A3B90715F4ABD9746B45D288F4C39CEB\Patches 3: 2 
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:851]: Executing op: ProductPublish(PackageKey={16910A63-C856-4377-AC40-E886CAD980B6})
1: {51709B3A-BA4F-479D-B654-2D884F3CC9BE} 
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:852]: Note: 1: 1402 2: UNKNOWN\Installer\Products\A3B90715F4ABD9746B45D288F4C39CEB 3: 2 
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:852]: Note: 1: 1402 2: UNKNOWN\Installer\Products\A3B90715F4ABD9746B45D288F4C39CEB 3: 2 
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:853]: Note: 1: 1402 2: UNKNOWN\Installer\Products\A3B90715F4ABD9746B45D288F4C39CEB 3: 2 
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:853]: Note: 1: 1402 2: UNKNOWN\Installer\Products\A3B90715F4ABD9746B45D288F4C39CEB 3: 2 
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:853]: Note: 1: 1402 2: UNKNOWN\Installer\Products\A3B90715F4ABD9746B45D288F4C39CEB 3: 2 
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:853]: Note: 1: 1402 2: UNKNOWN\Installer\Products\A3B90715F4ABD9746B45D288F4C39CEB 3: 2 
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:853]: Note: 1: 1402 2: UNKNOWN\Installer\Products\A3B90715F4ABD9746B45D288F4C39CEB 3: 2 
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:853]: Note: 1: 1402 2: UNKNOWN\Installer\Products\A3B90715F4ABD9746B45D288F4C39CEB 3: 2 
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:853]: Note: 1: 1402 2: UNKNOWN\Installer\Products\A3B90715F4ABD9746B45D288F4C39CEB 3: 2 
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:853]: Note: 1: 1402 2: UNKNOWN\Installer\Products\A3B90715F4ABD9746B45D288F4C39CEB 3: 2 
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:853]: Note: 1: 1402 2: UNKNOWN\Installer\Products\A3B90715F4ABD9746B45D288F4C39CEB 3: 2 
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:883]: Executing op: UpgradeCodePublish(UpgradeCode={3C229038-503A-495F-9581-4C30B2AE6523})
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:894]: Executing op: SourceListPublish(,,,,NumberOfDisks=1)
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:894]: Note: 1: 1402 2: UNKNOWN\Installer\Products\A3B90715F4ABD9746B45D288F4C39CEB\SourceList 3: 2 
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:903]: Executing op: ProductPublishClient(,,)
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:907]: Executing op: SourceListRegisterLastUsed(SourceProduct={51709B3A-BA4F-479D-B654-2D884F3CC9BE},LastUsedSource=C:\Temp\Windward_Installation_Files\)
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:907]: Entering CMsiConfigurationManager::SetLastUsedSource.
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:907]: Specifed source is already in a list.
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:907]: User policy value 'SearchOrder' is 'nmu'
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:908]: Adding new sources is allowed.
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:908]: Set LastUsedSource to: C:\Temp\Windward_Installation_Files\.
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:908]: Set LastUsedType to: n.
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:908]: Set LastUsedIndex to: 1.
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:57:910]: Executing op: End(Checksum=0,ProgressTotalHDWord=0,ProgressTotalLDWord=540126987)
MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:59:633]: Assembly Error:Access is denied.

MSI (s) (98:7C) [11:29:59:633]: Note: 1: 1935 2: {4CDEC9C7-0F61-41D8-8F19-DE1ADEB50D8D} 3: 0x80070005 4: IAssemblyCacheItem 5: Commit 6: IKVM.OpenJDK.XML.Crypto,version="8.5.0.2",culture="neutral",publicKeyToken="00D957D768BEC828",processorArchitecture="MSIL"
```

Comment: Not going to go off the rails with comments, but if you see problems on 2 out of 40000 computers I would call that "successful deployment". A certain percentage of computers will always fail (disk full, malware, disk corruptions, reboot needed first, security suite blocking, etc...). I have a couple of "ideas lists" on issues: [Deployment problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60374125/129130) and [the more comprehensive one here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130) - search for `"Generic Tricks"`. Will have a look at particulars above too.

Comment: There is some JDK stuff in there, maybe check that? Not sure what it is doing. Using Java? System Path check? First thing I always do is to try manual installation using a brand new or alternate admin account (profile issues), that is after I check disk space and run a disk scan and disable the security suite after a quick malware check and kick things off. New boxes? Focus: Runtime missing check. Old boxes? Focus: Malware check & disk space / errors.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul Unfortunately the two people unable to install don't care that the other 40K are good :(. Thank you for the lists.

Comment: Is there anything to find in the **Assembly Binding Log Viewer**? (**`FUSLOGVW.exe`** - somewhere under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\). Run as admin and enable custom logging maybe?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul That is a good idea - thank you

Comment: Did you google it?  https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.100004339

Comment: I'd need to see the entire log to give an answer. Look for my email address if you'd like to send it to me.