# Windows installer hangs during installing git

Tags: windows, git, installation, windows-installer, freeze

Trying to install git version 2.27.0 and installation stuck on 100%( full green bar).
I tried all the possible way like changing the install location path and with all the drive i have.but nothing worked.

When I asked my computer to restart and then canceling that....it takes me to the finish window but it worthless I could not run the git bash terminal.while trying to open git bash a file formed,named **mintty.exe.stackdump**

Please somebody help me to fix the issue....

[image: This is my stucked installer]

System: windows7 32bit

Comment: Can you open the Windows Event Viewer and look for errors?

Comment: Maybe try to re-download the installer? Where did you download it from? Do you have anti-virus software installed?

Comment: I have tried 6 to 7 times to re install it but nothing changed.....i downloaded from official website Of git ...no i don't have any antivirus software

Comment: @Bikram25 Did you try my suggestions below?

Comment: How is this question not yet deleted?

Answer (score 3):

***Logging***: This appears to be an [INNO setup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). Try to log it with:

```
Git-2.27.0-32-bit.exe /LOG
```

Then find the log file in the **`TEMP folder`** (sort it by modify time until you find the log file at the top).

---

***Updated***: [**"Short" list of things to check for a failing setup.exe**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60374125/129130)

---

[**I have a generic check list / ideas list for failing setups here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864). Check the ***"Generic Tricks"*** section for some suggestions. Here are some of the points as recommendations:

- Re-download the setup and virus check it. Quick malware scan of problem box.
- Verify disk space and check for disk errors on problem box.
- Temporarily disable your anti-virus during installation.
- Now try to log your setup as described above - on the problem box - and check for errors.

Further alternatives:

- Try to create a new admin account on problem box and install with a freshly downloaded and verified installer.
- Install on a virtual to make sure the install can succeed in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

First, as a workaround, you can at least simply uncompress [`PortableGit-2.27.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.27.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.27.0-64-bit.7z.exe), anywhere you want, and set your PATH:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

The other test you can do is simply to check if the issue persists with previous version of [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).