# MongoDB compass not initializing

Tags: database, mongodb, windows-installer, data-science, mongodb-compass

I am trying to install MongoDB compass, however, my screen is getting stuck at initializing screen. Please help me as I really need help here. Here are the entire details: -
OS - Windows 8.1 64bit

Powershell version - 4.0 (I also tried to change the execution policy remote assigned. but that also didn't help)

MongoDB server version - 4.2.0 stable (tried MSI version)

MongoDB compass version - tried both (1.23beta version and 1.22 stable version)

I have also tried to install and uninstall multiple times.

Could anyone please help me? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a verbose MSI log? If not, [please create one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453922/enable-installation-logs-for-msi-installer-without-any-command-line-arguments/54458890#54458890). Inline sample: `msiexec.exe /i C:\Path\Your.msi /L*vx! C:\Your.log`. There is also [this long list of issues to check for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130) (section *"Generic Tricks?"*). And there is [a shorter version of the list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60374125/129130).

Comment: My favorite option would be to try on a clean virtual. Install necessary runtimes manually first - if need be.

Comment: How does a verbose MSI log help?

Comment: Standard procedure for debugging to look in the log for clues (missing runtimes, failing custom actions, etc...). Did it help to install on a virtual? Do look in the log for any clues. Then check if your anti-virus is interfering by temporarily disabling it (if possible), check the box for malware and such things - the stuff found in those lists I linked to. Sometimes it is just a reboot that is needed. Also try to re-download the installation media. Run from an MSI copied to the local desktop too.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to run from an admin image (extracted files). This can be the case when you are on a slow machine with slow disk and an aggressive malware scanner (it scans the internal cabs and takes forever). Try to do an admin image and run from there? A bit far-fetched maybe, but give it a try: [administrative image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5751980/129130), [extracting files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24987512/129130). Here is the core of it: `msiexec.exe /A MySetup.msi TARGETDIR=D:\Extract\ /QN /L*V D:\Extract.log`

Comment: Hi Stein.. All this is quite technical for me. If you could help me explain in a layman language, it would be really helpful. Thanks!!

Comment: Also, one more thing.. I had installed it last time in my laptop. I decided to update the latest one from then this problem started.  There was a dialog box that came asking for reboot. which I clicked without reading carefully(my bad there).

Comment: `1)` I would try on another machine, maybe a virtual? `2)` You can also try to install using another login account for Windows (this can resolve user profile issues that block installers). `3)` If you show the short list above to your tech support guys, maybe they can look at it? It can take long to deal with these technicalities. `4)` For modern laptops (with SSD disks) a very common problem is lack of disk space.

Comment: Thanks Stein!! Probably reaching out to tech support guys might help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding this path `C:\Windows\System32\wbem` to your user Path variable?
I also had the same problem on Windows 10 and this has resolved my issue.

I found the fix there: https://dev.to/debugagrawal/fix-mongo-db-compass-initializing-screen-error-131e

Step by step instruction for less experienced Windows users:

1. Kill all running Compass instances using Task Manager (i.e. Ctrl + Shift + Esc, then find running instances, if any, and kill them with right click and **End task**)
2. Right click on **This PC** and then **Properties**
3. You should be in **Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System**
4. Click **Advanced system settings** link on left pane
5. On **System Properties** window go to **Advanced** tab
6. Click on **Environmental Variables** button closer to bottom of the page
7. Select **Path** in top list window (**User variables**)
8. Click **Edit** button located below that list window
9. Click **New** button to create new entry on the list
10. Paste **C:\Windows\System32\wbem** and click **OK**.
11. Another **OK** on **Environmental Variables** window
12. And another **OK** in **System Properties** window
13. Now you can try to run MongoDB Compass application again.

Answer (score 1):

Hey thanks for the [blog](https://dev.to/debugagrawal/fix-mongo-db-compass-initializing-screen-error-131e) mention , hope it worked. I faced the same issue while use MongoGUI so I figured out the way to fix it with help of environment variables.

To know more about environment variables you can read this blog, I referred to this to get more clarity on such kind of issues
https://www.digitalcitizen.life/simple-questions-what-are-environment-variables/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).