# Error in installing Python 3.10 in Windows 8.1

Tags: python, windows, installation, windows-installer

I am getting a fatal error (installation stops almost immediately) when I try to install Python 3.10 (the latest version, as proposed in python.org now) in my Windows 8.1 machine.

I checked the log file and the error is during the installation of msi. After searching the web I found related issues with other py versions and/or Windows versions. So far I have tried:

- Running as admin
- Stopping the msiexec process
- `msi unreg` and `msi regserver`

Nothing worked. Any ideas?

UPDATE: Some more attempts and information

- Turning the antivirus off and trying again
- Installing in a difference account (but still the same machine)
- Python 3.8 works

I also read somewhere that some viruses can cause msi trouble so I am now in the process of cleaning up the pc. Once done I will try to update the question with msi logs.

Comment: The exact error from the MSI-log would help to debug this, you can look that up in the MSI SDK help file. [About MSI logging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54458890/129130). `1`) Download the installation media again, `2`)  reboot before installing, `3`) disable antivirus and try to install, `4`)  try to install on a virtual or a different physical computer, `5`)  check for malware, `6`)  verify that you have `core runtimes` installed (.NET, Java, whatever is needed by Python). [A messy check list (of sorts) here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60374125/129130).

Comment: Do install the MSI with admin privileges as you suggest, and try to run a different MSI to see if it completes without problems as a test to see if the problem is the Python MSI or the whole machine state.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul Are you referring to the msi installation media? (1 in your first comment?)? I never installed that (as far as I can recall). About 3 (and related to 5) no antivirus installed at the moment, only Windows defender. I'll try to figure out about the msi logs and edit to include them.

Comment: The installation media I refer to is the Python MSI installer itself.  You should re-download it to ensure it isn't corrupted in some fashion ([see section 2 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60374125/129130)).

Comment: @SteinÅsmul I actually downloaded twice (tried switching accounts to see if it helped but didn't include it in the post) so if there's any corruption of the installer it comes from my end.

Comment: Verbose log: `msiexec.exe /i C:\Path\Your.msi /L*v C:\Your.log` and then you search for "value 3" (without the quotes) in the log file as your first step ([why?](https://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/8/2/the-first-thing-i-do-with-an-msi-log/)). Any error codes?

Comment: Did you get this issue resolved?

Comment: Unfortunately no but didn't have much time to work on it lately. I will update the post to include some info from our comments.

Comment: It looks like there are many MSI files embedded in a setup.exe launcher. Do you know [how to extract files from such setup.exe wrappers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24987512/129130)? There is also a section on [WiX Burn setup.exe extraction in the MSI logging answer I refer to above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54458890/129130).